# Magento 2 - Product price plugin does not work on promotion

Tags: magento-2.1, plugin

I'm building a plugin to recalculate some base prices of my store using some atributes of the product. I'm using an interceptor(plugin) of **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getPrice()**.

The price is modified but when I apply a promotion it have not been afected.

For a $90 product, the price modification is +$10 so the "before price" showing is $100. I have a promotion of 20% so the "final price" have to be $80. instead it is showing $72.

It is posible than intercept another method after the product repository is loaded. Maybe before currency rate have applying?